# Inspection of tflite model with C++ API yields untraceable results

Tags: c++, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I want to inspect a tflite model with the C++ API provided by TensorFlow. I have successfully converted the model and got a reasonable result when taking a look at the visualization created by the visualize.py script (both the model and the vis can be found on my repo: https://github.com/DocDriven/tflite-cpp-api-tests).

However, if I load and inspect the model with the C++ API, I get surprising results. The following snippet tries to convince me that my model has a ridicolous amount of inputs, outputs and nodes.

```
const std::string model_path = "model.tflite";

// Load the model.
std::unique_ptr<tflite::FlatBufferModel> model = tflite::FlatBufferModel::BuildFromFile(model_path.c_str());
if (model == nullptr) {
    std::cerr << "Failed to build FlatBufferModel from file: " << model_path << std::endl;
    std::abort();
}

tflite::ops::builtin::BuiltinOpResolver resolver;
std::unique_ptr<tflite::Interpreter> interpreter;

if (tflite::InterpreterBuilder(model, resolver)(&interpreter) != kTfLiteOk) 
{
    std::cerr << "Failed to build interpreter." << std::endl;
}

if (interpreter->AllocateTensors() != kTfLiteOk) {
    std::cerr << "Failed to allocate tensors." << std::endl;
}

interpreter->ResetVariableTensors();

LOG(INFO) << "tensors size: " << interpreter->tensors_size() << std::endl;
LOG(INFO) << "nodes size: " << interpreter->nodes_size() << std::endl;
LOG(INFO) << "inputs: " << interpreter->inputs().size() << std::endl;
LOG(INFO) << "input(0) name: " << interpreter->GetInputName(0) << std::endl;
LOG(INFO) << "outputs: " << interpreter->outputs().size() << std::endl;
LOG(INFO) << "output(0) name: " << interpreter->GetOutputName(0) << std::endl;

int t_size = interpreter->tensors_size();
for (int i = 0; i < t_size; i++) {
  LOG(INFO) << i << ": " << interpreter->tensor(i)->name << ", " 
            << interpreter->tensor(i)->bytes << ", "
            << interpreter->tensor(i)->type << ", "
            << interpreter->tensor(i)->params.scale << ", "
            << interpreter->tensor(i)->params.zero_point << std::endl;
}
```

Console output:

```
tensors size: 37
nodes size: 11936128518282651046
inputs: 25344
input(0) name: dense/BiasAdd
outputs: 18446744073709501604
output(0) name: dense/BiasAdd
0: dense/BiasAdd, 160, 1, 0, 0
1: dense/LeakyRelu, 160, 1, 0, 0
2: dense/MatMul_bias, 160, 1, 0, 0
3: dense/kernel/transpose, 3600, 9, 0.00181895, 0
4: dense_1/BiasAdd, 40, 1, 0, 0
5: dense_1/MatMul_bias, 40, 1, 0, 0
6: dense_1/kernel/transpose, 1600, 1, 0, 0
7: dense_2/MatMul_bias, 40, 1, 0, 0
8: dense_2/kernel/transpose, 1600, 1, 0, 0
9: dense_3/BiasAdd, 4, 1, 0, 0
10: dense_3/LeakyRelu, 4, 1, 0, 0
11: dense_3/MatMul_bias, 160, 1, 0, 0
12: dense_3/kernel/transpose, 1600, 1, 0, 0
13: dense_4/BiasAdd, 4, 1, 0, 0
14: dense_4/MatMul_bias, 360, 1, 0, 0
15: dense_4/kernel/transpose, 3600, 9, 0.00192905, 0
16: input_1, 360, 1, 0, 0
17: lambda/Exp, 40, 1, 0, 0
18: lambda/add, 4, 1, 0, 0
19: lambda/mul, 40, 1, 0, 0
20: lambda/mul_1, 4, 1, 0, 0
21: lambda/random_normal, 4, 1, 0, 0
22: lambda/random_normal/RandomStandardNormal, 4, 1, 0, 0
23: lambda/random_normal/mean, 4, 1, 0, 0
24: lambda/random_normal/mul, 4, 1, 0, 0
25: lambda/random_normal/shape, 4, 2, 0, 0
26: lambda/random_normal/stddev, 4, 1, 0, 0
27:
```

Several things are going on here:

- the loop seems to stop in the middle of the execution. The last 10
  tensors seem to be hidden and cannot be printed. Code after the for
  loop executes normally.
- I get shown an absurd amount of inputs and outputs. The model is a
  variational autoencoder with a structure of [90, 40, 10, 40, 90] and
  float inputs/outputs. I expect to get a single tensor for input and
  output respectively.
- The correct input and output tensors do not seem to be known.

I am using TF-version 1.15 and a model with select_tf_ops enabled (ops that are not available for tflite are taken from tf). I want to utilize the information to calculate the amount of memory I need to provide.

**Q: Why am I getting these obviously wrong outputs?**

**EDIT:**
I have tried this with a simpler model consisting only of Dense layers, and I get the same behavior. I have also tried using the Python interpreter API and the output is consistent with the visualize.py output. Therefore, the C++ API seem to be buggy.

Answer (score 0):

The effects you are seeing happened to me recently and want to share my solution. I had cross compiled tensorflow lite on my PC and was building the application on the embedded device. Obviously the toolchains I used were not completely the same and appeared to be incompatible, leading to negatively sized containers, like you are seeing.

I resolved the issue by also cross compiling my application using the same toolchain as I used to build tensorflow. And that put things back to normal.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try adding these two lines after building the interpreter:

interpreter->AllocateTensors();
interpreter->ResetVariableTensors();

Then inspect the model.

Comment: I have fleshed out the code section and incorporated your suggestions. Unfortunately, they yield the same results as before. Could you please have a look again?